# HTML5 game - how to make image only render between specific x-y-coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html

During my summer vacation boredom took over, so I decided to start learning html5-games. In the process of making this very easy game somewhat better in functionality (logical, if you will) I ran into an issue I can't figure out myself. I hope you can guide me accordingly.

So I have race.html (which only has the Canvas to show to game in my webbrowser)
and I have game.js

It's a simply 2D car game. The car goes down a road and in order to not run out of fuel, it has to catch as many fuel-tanks as possible in order to win.

My problem lies in the process of getting the "fuel-tank-image" to render and reset only between the x and y coordinates of the 'road'. Currently it resets and renders all over te place but not specifically on the 'road' where the car is driving.

Here is my game.js code:

```
// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 768;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "img/map.png";

// car image
var carReady = false;
var carImage = new Image();
carImage.onload = function () {
    carReady = true;
};
carImage.src = "img/car.png";

// fuel image
var fuelReady = false;
var fuelImage = new Image();
fuelImage.onload = function () {
    fuelReady = true;
};
fuelImage.src = "img/fuel.jpg";

// Game objects
var car = {
    speed: 500 // movement in pixels per second
};
var fuel = {};
var fuelsCaught = 0;

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

// Reset the game when the player catches a fuel
var reset = function () {
    car.x = canvas.width / 3;
    car.y = canvas.height / 1.3;

    // Throw the fuel somewhere on the screen randomly [lengte(math random) keer breedte voor een random plaat in de oppervlakte)]
    fuel.x = 300 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 700));
    fuel.y = 400 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 550));
};

// Update game objects
var update = function (modifier) {
    if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        car.y -= car.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        car.y += car.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
        car.x -= car.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
        car.x += car.speed * modifier;
    }

    // Are they touching?
    if (
        car.x <= (fuel.x + 32)
        && fuel.x <= (car.x + 32)
        && car.y <= (fuel.y + 32)
        && fuel.y <= (car.y + 32)
    ) {
        ++fuelsCaught;
        reset();
    }
};

// Draw everything
var render = function () {
    if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }

    if (carReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(carImage, car.x, car.y);
    }

    if (fuelReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(fuelImage, fuel.x, fuel.y);
    }

    // Score
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
    ctx.font = "14px Helvetica";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillText("Fuel Tanks caught: " + fuelsCaught + "/100", 32, 32);
};

// The main game loop
var main = function () {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;

    update(delta / 1000);
    render();

    then = now;

    // Request to do this again ASAP
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

// Let's play this game!
var then = Date.now();
reset();
main();
```

**the emphasis is on this piece:**

```
// Throw the fuel somewhere on the screen randomly [lengte(math random) keer breedte voor een random plaat in de oppervlakte)]
    fuel.x = 300 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 700));
    fuel.y = 400 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 550));
```

I have altered the 300 and the 700 often in order to get a clear perspective on the correlation. But to no avail, because the reset is not logical.

this is the image of the **road** (which has a res of: 1024x768):

[image]

**this is the car:**

[image]

**And this is the fuel-tank:**
[image]

and the race.html code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Race</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="js/game.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The idea is to render/reset the fuel-tank between the road sides and just above the car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fun. So let's say we start by defining the Y coordinate. Y can be between the top of the road and the bottom or the canvas (or `400` as you've given). Your code does this:

```
fuel.y = 400 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 550));
```

The road gets thinner and starts more towards the right towards the top, we need to define how this happens. Let's say that at the bottom of the screen it starts `10px` to the right, and at the maximum `y`, `y=1000px` it starts `600px` to the right. (*I've made these numbers up obviously, you'll have to refine them to suit your case*).

Let's also say that at the bottom of the screen the width is `600px` and at the top it is `30px`. We need to define two formulae to describe:

1. The left-most `x` coordinate for each `y` coordinate,
2. The road-width for each `y` coordinate.

Here:

```
var left_most_x = 10 + ((600-10)/1000) * fuel.y
var road_width = 600 - ((600-30)/1000) * fuel.y
```

Then you can define the `x` position as:

```
fuel.x = left_most_x + (Math.random() * road_width)
```

Comment: Very fun :) I'll try it out immediately, the gradual alteration of the width according to the road was in the back of my head, but I didn't know how to realize. You are a genius

Comment: Ha, thank you! If it works please come back and accept the answer :)

Comment: You have my promise, for now I have implemented the code and am starting the alter some of the numerics in order to have the satisfactory output. I'll let you know.

Comment: Jup, got it working nicely, I changed my fuel.y 400 value to 500. And made the fuel tank render a bit more above the car. Thank you again